# How to access variable in yaml file in linux CLI?

Tags: linux, sed, yaml, environment-variables, conda

I have a config.yaml that contains userId, userPassword and conda environment name:

```
userId: foo_name
userPassword: foo_pw 
conda_env_name: test_env
```

I would like to access the `conda_env_name` to read the user's desired conda name and I can run something like `conda env create -f environment.yml -n ${conda_env_name}`. How do I achieve this in linux CLI **without installing any pip packages**?

Comment: Your edit doesn't really invalidate the duplicate; it has an answer in Awk which is part of any basic Unix-like OS. (`pip` is a tool for installing Python packages, not shell utilities, though.)